# Never reaching if statement nested in for loop

Tags: lua

Basically what I am trying to do is compare `maxGuesses` to the third element in each row of `fullTable`, and for all of the ones that are equal I want to print the name. I have checked and the for loop is running the correct number of times, but the if statement never seems to evaluate to true. Any help would be appreciated!

`fullTable` holds:

```
name1    p    14
name2    p    5
name3    p    14
name4    p    14
```

Max guesses holds the higherst number in column 3, which is 14.

```
for i, data in ipairs(fullTable) do
    if fullTable[i][3] == maxGuesses then
        print(fullTable[i][1])
    end
end
```

The output should look like:

```
name1
name3
name4
```

EDIT: The issue was that `fullTable[i][3]` was a string, and `maxGuesses` was an int. Changed to `tonumber(fullTable[i][3])`

Comment: is the value of maxGuesses = 14 when you enter the for loop?

Comment: Yes. Max guesses is 14 prior to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that fullTable[i][3] was a string, and maxGuesses was an int. Changed to tonumber(fullTable[i][3])